# Convert Rest Assured Response from text/event-stream to Json for schema validation

Tags: java, json, rest, stream, rest-assured

I would like to know how to convert a "text/stream-event" response to a json so I can use JSONSchemaValidator to check if it matches with response.

My rest call

```
 System.put.princt(given()
                .contentType(JSON)
                .when()
                .put("/mypath/"")
                .then()
                .response()
                .extract()
                .asString());
```

Response (text/stream-event)

```
id: 2
data: {
data:   "field1" : "something",
data:   "field2" : "something",
data: }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
String responseMsg = given()
            .contentType(JSON)
            .when()
            .put("/mypath/"")
            .then()
            .response()
            .extract()
            .asString();

DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(responseMsg);
String anId = doc.read("id");
```